# Add mail external address to Azure AD User Object

Tags: api, rest, email, office365

Currently we are creating users in Azure AD through Azure AD Graph API. Our users, among other thinks, uses Sharepoint Online and Skype for Bussiness Online. All of our users have his mailbox in an Exchange 2010 (on-premise), so they don't have the Exchange Online Plan. For  Skype for Bussiness integration with Outlook, it's needed that the mail attribute on the Azure AD object be the same as the mail address in Outlook. The problem is that this attribute is read only throug rest API, and only is populated when you assign a Exchange Online plan to the user. Also, in Sharepoint Online, we can't send notifications to these users because they sharepoint profile doesn't have an email address.

How I should inform the email adress to an Azure AD User using Rest API?

Regards

Comment: It seems that you want to integrating your on-premises identities with Azure Active Directory. Did you try to use Azure AD Connect? Refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/) to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: I knew about Azure AD Connect, but all the integration is already done using the Azure AD Graph API (and an Identity Manager). Thanks